# Is it possible to replace value of anchor tag with an image?

Tags: jquery

I want toreplace the anchor text with an image, I tried:

```
$('a.next').text('<img src="images/slider_arrowr.png">');
```

but that just printed `<img ...` on screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.html`, rather than `.text`.